# can we create static library of Ghostscript?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, static-libraries, ghostscript

I downloaded Ghostscript source-code from [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html)
and was successfully able to compile the code in Visual Studio. The libraries that are generated are dynamic libraries.
Right now struck with my work, as I wanted to statically link Ghostscript library to my application
so that I don't have to deliver any other binary along-with my C++ application.

Any suggestion or help is much appreciated ! Thank you very much

Comment: Looks like you are trying to violate GS license: `As soon as you want to distribute Ghostscript in a closed source, proprietary environment, deploy it in a SaaS environment OR wish to receive technical support from Artifex, you have to purchase an Artifex commercial license. Artifex is the exclusive licensing agent for Ghostscript.`

Comment: Hi @SergeyA we have the commercial license while not sure if it is possible to do a static linking

Comment: if you have commercial license, you should have support agreement w/ Artifex, and likely be in a position to ask them direct question.

Comment: As SergeyA says, if you have a commercial license for Ghostscript you should contact support@artifex.com and quote your customer number. A surprising number of people think they have a commercial license.....

Comment: Thanks for your input, i really appreciate it ! Indeed that would be the last option

Answer (score 0):

Just as the community members said, you have to contact with the the Artifex Team to get their permission.

And you can [pack them as a c++ nuget package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/native-packages) and then publish it into the your feed with their permission.